# How to compile (build) my Qt application to run on many linux distributions?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, compilation, distribution

I have created a Qt GUI application and I want to provide a linux executable that runs on as many distributions as possible. Is this possible or do I have to provide a separate executable for each distribution?

Thanks for your help

Comment: 10 questions an no accepted answer. Please read the F.A.Q if you want to receive answers to your questions.

Comment: Your comment is unclear, please elaborate "10 questions an no accepted answer.", thx

Comment: StackOverflow is not a regular forum website. But even a regular forum requires you to **first** read the F.A.Q. Please take the time to read it if you want us to take the time to read your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base).  It is a standard which many distributions follow to allow an application compliant with the LSB to run on any of them.  That should be a good start.  If your app is LSB compliant, there really isn't much more that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Statically linking your Qt libraries into your executable will increase your distributable size, but you will not have to worry about having the proper Qt libraries installed.

Take a look at the documentation here:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/deployment-x11.html#static-linking

Hope this helps.